# MySQL query - weight-based search engine

Tags: mysql, optimization, search-engine

Here is the database structure for a medical MIS table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ab_med` (
  `med_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `med_title` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_posted_date` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_company_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_experience` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_salary` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_city` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_description_short` text,
  `med_details_link` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_from_city_type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `med_from_city` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_collected_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `med_status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`med_id`),
  KEY `MedCity` (`med_city`),
  KEY `MedTitle` (`med_title`),
  KEY `MedCompany` (`med_company_name`),
  KEY `MedExperience` (`med_experience`),
  KEY `med_details_link` (`med_details_link`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `med_index` (`med_title`,`med_company_name`,`med_description_short`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=639295 ;
```

There are around 0.5 million records. A user can search using 2 fields:

1. Keyword
2. Location

Keyword is looked into `med_title`, `med_company_name`, `med_description_short`, `med_city` as per the score.

Location is looked into `med_city`

I've used full text mysql search but I need the most recent entries to show up with better score. I'm not getting the SQL query for it. I'm using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT distinct(med_details_link),med_id,med_title,med_posted_date,med_company_name,med_description_short,med_from_city,med_experience,med_city,med_collected_time,MATCH (med_title,med_company_name,med_description_short) AGAINST ('+hello +world' IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score
FROM ab_med
WHERE MATCH (med_title,med_company_name,med_description_short) AGAINST ('+hello +world' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by med_id desc limit 1000
```

Suppose I search for "hello world", I understand that there should be weight based on:

1. title would have highest weight
2. company name will have weight less than title but more than description
3. description will have least weight

Please help in getting a SQL query to consider all these weights and search efficiently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider turning to Sphinx to get a satisfactory solution to this problem.

With 5 million rows, and the requirements you have, the performance of MySQL fulltext search will be disappointing.

Comment: Will you suggest the same even with 0.5 million records? The database will grow down the line though. Also, any specific information on use of sphinx for my specific case?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036666/guide-to-using-sphinx-with-php-and-mysql