# php mysql fulltext search order by relevance

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, relevance

How to make a php fulltext search order by relevance?

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2,col3) 
AGAINST ('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
Order By relevance
```

I want to set the relevance, first should match `col1, col2` then then match `col3`, for more words if `col1, col2` finished match, then turn in `col3`.

Maybe I should set a percentage, like `col1, col2` with 66% relevance and `col3` with 34% relevance...

Comment: You might wanna take a look at 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547542/how-can-i-manipulate-mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-to-make-one-field-more-valu

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7115221/mysql-query-weight-based-search-engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
SELECT *, (MATCH(col1, col2) AGAINST('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.66 + MATCH(col3) AGAINST('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE) * 0.34) AS relevance
FROM table
WHERE MATCH(col1, col2, col3) AGAINST ('+$boolean' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```