# Trouble creating a function that searches 1+ databases based on relevant keywords

Tags: php, mysql, keyword

Okay, so I have written this script which allows me to find however it does not work correctly.  I am having a programming issue - programming this to work correctly. It does not seem to be working correctly.

This function is declared on each row that shows up within a database full of payments from a bank statement.  The `$a, $b, $c, $d` is simply the type (BAC, TRS, etc), description (35 QUEENS ROAD RENT) and amount (£500.00).

I am trying to create a function that will reconcile payments to a particular user, depending on what addresses/properties are connected to them, their name and how much their rent is.

This is what I have so far:

```
   function reconcile($a,$b,$c,$d) {

    //when the user clicks on the text fild, jquery loads the various names needed from the database
    //when the user clicks on the selected field, the value is saved via ajax and saved on the server the reconciled field

    //break down the inputs into an array
    //create SQL query that matches all of these key words

    //create keywords database
    $keywords = $a . " " . $b . " " . $c . " " . $d;

    //remove commas, dashes and other keywords from database that might be a nuisance
    //change names like ave to avenue
    $keywords = str_replace("'", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("-", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace(",", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("A/C", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("TO", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("CALL", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("REF.NO.", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("TO", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = preg_replace("/\s+/", " ", $keywords);
    $keywords = str_replace("  ", "", $keywords);
    $keywords = addslashes($keywords);
    $keywords = mysql_real_escape_string($keywords);

    $keywords = explode(" ", $keywords);
    //$keywords = remove_from_array($keywords, 2);




    //match keywords to keywords database

    $matches = array();

    //search 5 databases...

    $i=0;

    foreach($keywords as $keyword) {

        //add more fields
        //check distinct

        //do not allow any keywords that are smaller than 3
        if(strlen($keyword) < 3) {
            continue;
        }

        $get = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT `users`.`id` FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `addresses` ON `users`.`id` = `addresses`.`user` WHERE (`users`.`fname` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `users`.`lname` LIKE '%$keyword%') OR (((`addresses`.`flat` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `addresses`.`address` LIKE '%$keyword%') OR (`addresses`.`district` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `addresses`.`town` LIKE '%$keyword%')) OR (`addresses`.`county` LIKE '%$keyword%' OR `addresses`.`postcode` LIKE '%$keyword%'));") or die("Error: " . mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($get) > 0) {
            while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($get)) {
                list($uid) = $fetch; //$uid = user id
                //insert $uid into array
                //1 => 3 times
                //find number if exists and then add to that number

                //search array and echo attempts (if any)

                if(in_array($uid, $matches)) {
                    //add one to the key
                    $matches[$uid]++;
                } else {
                    array_push($matches, $uid);
                }

                $i++;

                //save search to database

            }

            //create array for user
            //add up relevance for that user

        }

    }

    $relevance = 0;

    if($i > $relevance) {
        //change javascript function and link with ajax.php
        echo "<span onClick=\"javascript:void(0)\" style=\"cursor:pointer;\" class=\"label label-success\">Accept</span>\n\r";
        //change to jquery function that allows a drop down of names from the database
        echo "<input type=\"text\" style=\"width:140px\" value=\"" . $matches[0] . "\" />\n\r";
    }

}
```

I was thinking of adding an array that does this:

`[0] (user id) => 3 (how many times that user id is found through one row of a bank statement)`

So for example, if user 3 owned a property at 37 Kings Avenue, and the keyword was 'Avenue', the result would be `[3] => 1` and so on for extra users.

The 'accept' button means that the user would accept the system's reconciliation and the text input would show a drop down of other relevant names/all names and addresses.

Comment: This question is hard to answer as asked. You state that "none seem to work correctly."  Can you be more specific?  Also, have you investigated MySQL's full text search capability.

Comment: I'm looking for a better solution rather than searching through all 5+ databases one at a time through each keyword that is picked up. I have investigated MySQLs full text search capability but only since today. I would be grateful if you could provide some examples that you think would work well with this issue.

Comment: Pardon my frankness, but you are asking a question like this, "I'm thinking of building a kitchen. Can you recommend a type of cupboard that will serve as oven, fridge, storage, and trash bin? I don't want to have all those different things in my kitchen.  Tenants, landlords, properties, and agreements all have very different characteristics as data items at the lowest level of your system. If you are going to provide a uniform search interface to your users you're going have to do a lot of work to adapt each data type.

Comment: It's not necessarily a search but more of a reconciliation so the bank statements can match up to a particular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search some data from your databases/tables/views you can use [SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com) [Data search](http://www.webyog.com/blog/2011/06/09/mysql-data-search-data-at-your-finger-tips/) feature. It searches data in your server. It works like Google search! The 'Data Search' feature lets you find specific data without actually writing any SQL. You can filter the data by the datatypes/subset of databases or tables.

You can try downloading the [30-day trial](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) and evaluate this MySQL GUI.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is also [sphinx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036666/guide-to-using-sphinx-with-php-and-mysql) ([Official site](http://sphinxsearch.com/)), check it out if you have root access to your server so you can run the server process it requires. It's easy to setup and it's very good with giving relevant results, you can get all the matches for a keyword or a set of keywords, so you can basically throw all your keywords to it and it will give you all the results, with the best match on top.

Also it's very fast, allows for delta indexing (adding new data without having to go through all the data to rebuild the index) so you can run your full re-indexing during off peak times.

If you want it really easy I would recommend using the MySQL plugin [SphinxSE](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/sphinxse-snippets.html) which will allow you to query it like a normal mysql table and do a join to the original tables for easy access.

If you use [gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) you can simply add mysql with the plugin already by using this [ebuild](https://github.com/castiel/gentoo-overlay/blob/master/dev-db/mysql/mysql-5.1.59-r1.ebuild)